# Sitecore Single Language Publish in multilingual Sitecore Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-mvc

Is there any way to publish items in sitecore for some specific language that we get from API associated with the item?

```
Language[] languages = new Language[] { LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en") };
....
...
Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishSmart(master, targetDbs, languages);
```

I have three language in Sitecore Env Here but I want one item to publish for just "en" language and other for just "en-ca" and other for just "fr-ca".

Comment: use PublishItem separate for different items.

Comment: @Anton , Thanks for your reply , Can you be more descriptive on this.

Comment: I meant that if you need to publish certain item in one language and other items for different language and you know what item should be published to what language  then you can use Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishItem instead of PublishSmart

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the `PublishItem` method and proceed as follows:

1. Get the items that needs to be published.
2. Get the language versions of each item to know in which language the items need to be published.

**Sample Code**

```
//Get your Item list here
var itemList = GetItemList();

//Loop in the Item list to get the languages
//Publish the item based on the languages
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    var languageVersions = item.Languages;

    Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishItem(item, targetDb, languageVersions, true, false);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Hishaam , i was able to do this and it worked , but the item which i published in just one language is also displaying in other language as well . diff is when i am trying to open the product in non published language , it redirects me to its homepage and on published language , it works good. The product should display only on published language page.

Comment: Does the other version also available in the target database?

Comment: Yes all the versions are present in target database. In content editor , I am able to see correct version in which item is published . But on website , it opens in all the languages.

Comment: If all the versions of the items have been published to the target database, it will open on the live site

Comment: Issue was because of installation problem on the environment itself . Code was fine. Thanks.